# How to hide the navigation bar and the status bar on Android only when keyboard is shown?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard for android, full screen, i want to hide the navigation bar and the status bar on Android only when keyboard is shown and then return the same state.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

Use the above given code to hide the status bar from the app. Also, don't forget to apply your keyboard visible condition.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. That works if i'm in an Activity.  I have this class "extends InputMethodService"